# Open a web page in new window when clicked on a image in slider

Tags: javascript, simplemodal, new-window

I am interning at a startup which makes custmized systems. So basically, I am trying to implement a slider, which will put up slide show of images of motherboard, processors etc, and when the user clicks on the image, the page should open up with processor list( as in a typical e-com store). I want to open the page in a new window(NOT tab) or a modal box restoring the session so that the item added to the cart retains when we return to the slider page. I want to keep things easy and use JS only. Is it possible.

Comment: If you just want to open a popup, look at `window.open();`. Quick example : `window.open("http://www.example.com", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");`. If you don't specify the third parameter, it will open in a new tab for the recent  browsers.

Comment: Yes I am doing this only. But will the item I add to the cart in this window retain when I return back to main page?

Comment: No. To do "real time updates", you will need to do Ajax calls to some script returning the mst recent data to check if your client has added an item to the cart in the other page.